# Whats is Burstable instance in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Whats is burstable instance in GCP? Does it mean , that instance can be automatically deleted if other devices need quota? Is it same as preemptive instance?

Answer (score 1):

Shared-core machine types offer bursting capabilities that allow instances to use additional physical CPU for short periods of time. Bursting happens automatically when your instance requires more physical CPU than originally allocated. During these spikes, your instance will opportunistically take advantage of available physical CPU in bursts. Note that bursts are not permanent and are only possible periodically. Bursting doesn't incur any additional charges. You are charged the listed on-demand price for f1-micro, g1-small, and e2 shared-core machine types.

See also:

- [CPU bursting](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#cpu-bursting)

Comment: Thanks @Kolban, why should use choose normal instances over burstable instances If burstable instances can provide such cpu autoscaling benefit?

Comment: If I'm reading this document correctly ... https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#sharedcore ...CPU Bursting is only available on what Google calls "Shared Core" machines.  The key doc is "In general, shared-core instances can be more cost-effective for running small, non-resource intensive applications than standard, high-memory or high-CPU machine types."   The shared core machines are the smallest (and cheapest) configuration.  Many clients find these machines under powered for their needs and need the standard and higher machines.